# How to Import Excel data to MYSql database table using c# MVC 5?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, mysql, model-view-controller

```
public List<List<string>> GetListFromExcel(string FileName)
{
    try
    {
        List<List<string>> sListOfRecords = new List<List<string>>();
        IExcelDataReader reader = null;
        using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(FileName))
        {
            string sExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileName);
            if (sExtension == ".xls")
            {
                reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
            }
            else
            {
                reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
            }
            reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
            DataSet result = reader.AsDataSet();
            reader.Close();
            DataTable data = result.Tables[0];
            var excelColdata = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
            {
                var excelRowdata = new List<string>();
                foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    excelRowdata.Add(item.ToString());
                }
                if (excelRowdata.Where(m => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m)).Count() > 0)
                {
                    sListOfRecords.Add(excelRowdata);
                }
            }
        }

        return sListOfRecords.Distinct().ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ServiceUtil.LogError(ex);
        log.Error("Error", ex);
        throw ex;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please briefly explain what you have done to solve this problem and what doesn't work for you.

Comment: ExcelDataReader has detailed instructions on how to use it [here](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader).  If you're having difficulty using it, focus your question on the specific problem you're having.